# How do I transfer the Militech Datashard eddies to myself?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

During one of the early missions in the game, you are tasked with collecting a Flathead robot from a Maelstrom hideout. I resolved the optional objective to chat to Militech about it, and received the Militech Datashard - meant for paying off the Maelstrom gang, but I ended up resolving that quest a... different way.

I hacked into the shard and V had a line about confirming that it was legit. However, the Shard menu now shows the Shard as 'read' and I didn't receive the money from it.

Is it possible to get this money from the shard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the shard is hacked, an item will appear in your Backpack called the 'Hacked Militech Datashard'

[image: Shard in the player's backpack]

Left-clicking on it will initially appear to do nothing, **however**, if you back out of all the menus, you'll get a red Cyberware message saying 'Transferring Funds':

[image: Transferring Funds]

After which you'll see that the $10k is added to your account:

[image: Account popup]